# How to capture Image while video recording in ios swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am recording 5 seconds of video successfully by using the following code. but I need to capture an image while recording video. First of all I want to know is it possible to capture image while recording.If it is possible how to do this task in ios swift3. My Actual task is that I need to capture and save one video and one image every 5 seconds when user clicked on the button.could anyone guide me to do this task.

```
func VideoCaptureMethod() {
    //self.cameraView = self.view

    self.cameraManager.resumeCaptureSession()


    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)


    for device in devices {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back{


            do{

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                    }

                    captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                    captureSession.startRunning()

                    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                    let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mov")
                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
                    movieOutput.startRecording(to: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)



                    let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 5
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
                        print("stopping")
                        self.movieOutput.stopRecording()


                    }
                }

            }
            catch{

                print("Error")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv4cJf5qdu0 This will help you

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will try this